# Bootstrap breaks out when using push-pull

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using  basic bootstrap feature to change the column position based on the screen width.

I want to show column 2 before column 1 for large & medium. For small I want to show column 1 first & then column 2. which is working but problem i am facing is columns break out of  `row` container & take the full width when screen is less then 1000 pixels. how can i keep then with the container  class `container content-wrapper`

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="container content-wrapper"> 
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-push-7 gb-red">
            1 IMAGE
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-pull-5 gb-green">
                2 TEXT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CodePen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aYjQVZ

[image]

Comment: change "col-md-" to "col-sm-" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version it breaks down because of *breakpoints* in `bootstrap` .

> /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) `'sm'`
>
> /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) `md`
>
> /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) `'lg'`

You only mentioned `'md'` and `lg` , thats why your code breaks from **(992px to 768px)**

I have inserted **`col-sm-5`** and **`col-sm-7`** respectively to avoid break down.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="container content-wrapper"> 
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5  col-sm-push-7 bg-info">
                Col 1111
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 bg-danger">
                Col 2222
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v3.3.6 while you are using Bootstrap v3.3.7 is that the reason

Comment: @Learning Nothing with versions

Comment: so what is the change i cant see it

Comment: @Learning i will explain in the answer

Comment: I noticed the change, It would be nice to explain for other users also

Answer (score 0):

Change col-md-5 and col-md-7 to col-sm or add class for col-sm.

Your problem is because you don't specify a width for your div for device with width less than 1000px so your divs take 100% but keep the marges.
When you add col-sm classes you specify a width and fix the problem.